# How can test the content beyond a String?

Tags: java

I need to take an input (a tweet), and tell the user how many mentions and hashtags there are, if the input is a valid length (max = 148 characters), and if the message was re-tweeted (by looking for "RT:").

I already worked out the cap-length, and re-tweets, but I can't seem to figure out how counting the hash and mentions would work. This is what I've come up with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tweet.length(); i++) {
    if ((tweet.charAt(i) == '#') && (tweet.charAt(i+1) != ' ')) {       
        hash++;
    }
}
```

The problem I face is that if there is a hashtag or mention at the end of the string the variable goes out of bounds and I get an Index range Exception. So I need help finding out how I can get the same effect without the exception while not counting the char at the end.

The mention "function" will work the exact same way as the hash  "function".

Comment: Instead of `#charAt(i + 1)`, try using `#indexOf(' ', /* starting index */)`, then you can find the indexes of the hashtag and substring. Additionally if you don't mind regex you can split on `' '` and then check if a word begins with `#`

Comment: Well, test that i + 1 is less than the length of the string.

Comment: @cricket_007 Looks to me like it's *excluding* hash followed by space.

Comment: @shmosel I'm reading this as "if there is a hash, followed by space, increment the number of seen hashtags". I assume the mentions work the same way for the `@` character

Comment: @cricket_007 It's checking for a `#`, followed by a non-space character (note the `!= ' '`), and counting that as a hashtag.

Comment: Oh... oops `!=`. Gotcha..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `i < tweet.length() - 1` in your `for` loop.

Comment: Assuming OP doesn't want to count trailing a hash.

Comment: @shmosel That's implied by the conditions within the for loop -- a token is considered a hash if it begins with `#` and is immediately followed by a non-space character. That can't happen at the end of the string. (Also, considering the context of twitter mentions/hashtags, a trailing `#` wouldn't be tagging anything, so there would be no reason to count that).

Comment: *followed by a non-space character* is only your interpretation. Technically speaking, it could just as well be interpreted as *not followed by a space character*.